# Make a phone call from custom widget

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I was wondering if it is posible to create a simple widget button in notification bar that makes a phone call when you click on it.
I have been reading apple's documentation and one restriction is:

> Access a sharedApplication object, and so cannot use any of the methods on that object

As far as I know, you need to access to UIApplication.sharedInstance to perform a call.

Any ideas about that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I respond to myself.

After researching information and creating a project from scratch I found that to make a phone call you should use this code:

```
 let phoneNumber: String = "1234567890"
    let phoneNumberString: String = "tel:\(phoneNumber)"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: phoneNumberString)!

    self.extensionContext!.openURL(url, completionHandler: { (Bool) in
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this to text

```
let phoneNumber: String = "1234567890"
let phoneNumberString: String = "sms:\(phoneNumber)"
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: phoneNumberString)!
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

and this to call

```
let phoneNumber: String = "1234567890"
let phoneNumberString: String = "tel:\(phoneNumber)"
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: phoneNumberString)!
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

Comment: hello @Sethmr thanks for your response. I know how to make a phone call but I want to perform it from a widget and as apple says a restriction is : "Access a sharedApplication object, and so cannot use any of the methods on that object"

Comment: I'm unsure of what you are asking.